# Metric tensor operator

Tags: operators, metric-tensor, soft-question, quantum-gravity

Please excuse me if the question doesn't make any sense. I'm only an interested layman.

One of the main principles of quantum physics is that a measurable is given by an operator $H$ acting over a vector space $V$. The measured quantity then would be an eigenvalue of $H$. If we consider the components $g_{ij}$ of the metric tensor $g$ as measurables, then it would be natural to assume the existence of some operators $H_{ij}$ such that the measurement gives
$$H_{ij}(x)v_x=g_{ij}(x)v_x$$
where $x$ runs over our universe manifold $M$, and $v_x$ belongs to a vector space $E_x$. Of course, $g_{ij}$ would be quantized and no longer interpreted as a metric tensor, but we can assume that the average value $\langle g_{ij}(x)\rangle$ behaves as a metric tensor (that is, $\langle g_{ij}(x)\rangle$ is governed by Einstein equations).

My questions are:

- Is there any research in quantum gravity following this direction or having an alike consequence?
- If there is, can we describe $H$ coordinate-freely? And what is $g_{ij}$'s interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is not correct.

Thr values of $g_{\mu \nu}$ are not observables nor measurable.

Metric gives you Christoffel symbols and the Christoffel symbols give you the geodesic equations. Christoffel symbols are called connection.

This is not the only way to the to the geodesic equations. You can find the equation of motion with a totally different connect which is not related to any metric at all.
The connections which are related to the same geodesic corresponds to a class of connections which are related by projective transformation.

Metric is just a convenient tool to calculate the geodesic but not the only way. This means that it is not measurable or observable.

Quantization of gravity has already been done in string theory. The hard part about quantization of gravity is that the cross section of the interaction goes to infinity and it is not an easy fix. String theory provides one way to do it mathematically.

Finally, what you defined as H may not exist at all because GR equations are highly non linear while Schrodinger equation is linear. So you cannot use the same trick.

Comment: Thanks! If I replace the tensor metric $g_{ij}$ with the connections $\Gamma_{ijk}$, or with any suitable set of parameters describing the spacetime, would it make any sense?

Comment: No. As I said connection is not unique either.

Comment: I disagree, the metric corresponds to our physical devices to measure distances and interval of times. What is disputable is whether or not there is a quantum observable corresponding to it. I do not think so  for many reasons of various nature.

Comment: Consider a coordinate system viewed as a set of devices associating four numbers to events. We have a lots of similar systems and we use them everyday. Given two events we can measure the distance between them with  instruments. I admit that the best situation to do it  is when the spacetime is static. However once the spatial and temporal distance is computed it can be written as a quadratic form of the difference of empirical coordinates: that is the metric.

Comment: Gauss explored the nature of the real spatial metric using an optical reference frame.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Would you mind elaborating your last comment about Gauss? I don't see how it is related to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Gauss tried to understand if the spatial geometry is really Euclidean making some (in his view) large scale measurements.

Comment: @ValterMoretti and if you have time, perhaps you can also write down some reasons for which you think there is no quantum observable corresponding to the metric, or more generally, to the spacetime's geometry?

Comment: I do not think that the spacetime cannot have some quantum nature, who knows, but I do not think the way to find that structure is a naive quantizatiin if the metric. First of all what is the quantum system the metric operator refers to? There is a different metric operator for every particle?

Comment: That is only a feeling of mine, many years ago I published a paper about Lorentzian non commutative geometry (you can find it since it is still quoted sometime). After that paper I decided to give up with these issues. Too far from testable physics...

Comment: Thanks! Your comments are helpful.